# Google Sheet Chart's Data Range (in Chart Editor) formula from cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a chart in Google Sheets, the "Data Range" is as follows...

```
MIR!J1:K4547,DIR!K1:K4547
```

What I am trying to do is reference a cell value for sheet "MIR" and "DIR" values.

Let's say I edit cell A1 to ZIR...

then the data range changes to

```
ZIR!J1:K4547,DIR!K1:K4547
```

I searched intensively in Google but maybe I am not using right keywords, will appriciate some feedback on this...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request. You want the `Data Range` to change whenever the spreadsheet is edited? Could you please provide more details on this, and provide a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on (free of sensitive information)? Finally, are you open to using Apps Script? If you want to make changes when the spreadsheet is edited, you might want to use an `onEdit` trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what type of chart you are trying to get, but you could create a dynamic range, however, this would only work for a line graph.

1. Choose any cell and enter this formula: `=A1&"!K1:J4547"`
2. Go to `Data > Named Ranges` and make the cell with the formula the named range. *(This step is optional, but will make things easier)*

You can now use this range for other formulas, for example, if you want a line graph: `=SPARKLINE(INDIRECT(dynamicRange))`
[image: line graph example]

Reference: https://www.benlcollins.com/formula-examples/dynamic-named-ranges/

---

While writing this, I also realized a different work around, but using the same idea. Using the `QUERY` function, you can grab cell values, without needing to change the chart range. For example, placing the formula `=QUERY(INDIRECT(A3))` in a cell, will grab all the values from DIR!K1:J4547. Changing the value of A1 in the sheet will change the sheet that it grabs from. From there, set the chart range to wherever you place the `QUERY` formula.
[image: Query example]

You could also just do `=QUERY(INDIRECT(A3))`, the named range is not necessary.

---

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

What I had done is the following

I created an empty spreadheet and used 3 columns on that sheet to construc the chart. Then I have created a script (I know very dirty code but it works).

The script replaces the data on the last sheet I created as follows:

```
function replace() {
  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CHART'); // or whatever is the name of the sheet 
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1); 
var range2 = sheet.getRange(1,2); 
var data = range.getValue();
var data2 = range2.getValue();
var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(data);
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ChartData");
var sheet2From = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(data2);
var sheet2To = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ChartData");
// Copy from 17th row, 4th column, all rows for one column 
var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(1, 10, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
var valuesToCopy2 = sheetFrom.getRange(1, 11, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
var valuesToCopy3 = sheet2From.getRange(1, 11, sheet2From.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
//Paste to another sheet from first cell onwards
sheetTo.clearContents();
sheetTo.getRange(1,sheetTo.getLastColumn()+1,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
sheetTo.getRange(1,sheetTo.getLastColumn()+1,valuesToCopy2.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy2);
sheetTo.getRange(1,sheet2To.getLastColumn()+1,valuesToCopy3.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy3);}
```

For changing the Data Range I pulled data from the cells.